# Different layouts for landscape mode on tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am writing an application in which I am required to write different layouts for different screen orientations.

Let me explain my use case for someone to give me a direction. What I have:

An `activity` in my project has 3 `Fragment`s in a `ViewPager` in portrait mode which remain as it is for landscape mode on phones and portrait on tablets. This part is working and all the functionality has been written as per requirement.

Now, we need to write for landscape mode on tablets which will show all the 3 layouts in the `Fragment`s from `ViewPager` in one layout. So, what I have done is

1. layout/activity_main.xml - has a `ViewPager` and load `Fragment`s using `FragmentPagerAdapter`, it is working for both phones (port, land) and tablets (port)
2. layout-sw600dp-land/activity_main.xml - has a `FrameLayout` where I'm adding a `Fragment`   by first checking that `viewPager == null` i.e. the content view is set to `activity_main.xml` from `layout-sw600dp-land`

But this is resulting in following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sf.quid/com.sf.quid.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030024
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3738)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030024
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.sf.quid.fragment.MainFragment.onCreateView(MainFragment.java:23)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1097)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1895)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3738)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And, it is happening on Nexus 7 tab when

1. Open the app in portrait mode
2. switch to landscape mode (shows the layout from layout-sw600dp-land)
3. switch to portrait results in **Crash** with above error log

Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: I am facing the same problem as well. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, I have it working. I will post the answer here over the weekend.

Comment: The weekend never came :-|